# How to model a flial?

Tags: modeling, particles, normals

How can I rotate them correctly? I want it with a patricle system so i can quickly add more spikes if needed

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *Properties* panel > *Particles*, enable the *Advanced* option, then activate the *Rotation* option and choose *Normal* in the *Initial Rotation* dropdown menu. If you enable the *Scale* and *Rotation* option under *Render*, the scale and rotation of the peak object in the global scene will be reproduced, it can be handy.

[image]

Comment: Ohh nice trick with the object rotation. thanks for the quick and good reply!